# How can I use my eXtplorer in a web redirected domain?

Tags: redirect, web

I am using eXtplorer which works perfectly in almost any fixed domain/hosting service.

Now I am experiencing an issue and I would appreciate a lot some support.

My domain is having a web-redirect in the main domain's name. So, if I placed the eXtplorer files in a folder at the root of "public_html", and I get an "500 Internal error" which also includes a 404 Not found as you can see in this screenshot.

[image]

My current domain is http://diariodebate.info/ and the redirect is http://panucoaldia.diariodebate.info/ The files are inside of http://diariodebate.info/eXtplorer and I have already tried to place the files inside of the "panucoaldia" folder with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well... I am answering the question just for someone else coming here looking for an answer. Finally the problem itself was that certain files/folders didn't have the proper permissions. After all and somehow, in order to eXtplorer (and some other tools like Wordpress) needs 755 for folder and 644 for files.

Took a while to get that trick but that's it!

Thank you.